# Very poor webserver performance

Tags: performance, nginx, cloudflare

so i ran this command "ab -c 50 -n 5000 http://lala.la" today on the server, and i got these "amazing" results:

```
Document Path:          /
Document Length:        26476 bytes

Concurrency Level:      50
Time taken for tests:   1800.514 seconds
Complete requests:      2427
Failed requests:        164
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 164, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      65169733 bytes
HTML transferred:       64345285 bytes
Requests per second:    1.35 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       37093.408 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       741.868 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          35.35 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   2.7      0      22
Processing:  4335 36740 9513.2  33755  102808
Waiting:        7 33050 8655.1  30407   72691
Total:       4355 36741 9512.4  33755  102808

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  33754
  66%  37740
  75%  40977
  80%  43010
  90%  47742
  95%  56277
  98%  62663
  99%  71301
 100%  102808 (longest request)
```

This is on a newly installed Nginx server, using Cloudflare and APC.

Dont think ive ever seen such poor performance, so what the heck can be causing it?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't know until you start troubleshooting, but my guess would be trying to serve too many requests at a time leading to memory exhaustion and paging.

Comment: The fact that you mention APC makes me think that this is actually 'poor PHP performance.'  How complex is your front page?

Comment: I recommend updating your question to explain the research you have done yourself to look into the issue. Since the problem could be in any number of places, you would do well to spell out all the major software, hardware, and networking components involved and what you have done to tune them and understand their performance individually.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try testing directly to the origin and take cloudflare out of the mix (unless you have the html as cacheable and you're trying to test cloudflare's ability to serve it).  Given that one of cloudflare's purposes is to protect sites it's not unreasonable to think that your test might be getting rate limited (at a minimum, bypassing it will remove a possible source of investigation).

Add $request_time to your access log format for nginx and that will tell you the server-side view of performance.  If it still looks horrible you might have to use something like New Relic or DynaTrace to get more detail on where the time is going (if you don't instrument the app itself).

Are you using php-fpm for connecting nginx to php?  If not, you should look into it.

For times that are that bad, odds are it's in the actual application though and not so much in the config.